# Are aqueous solutions of oxidizing agents safe?

Tags: redox, aqueous-solution, safety

In the "[reducing agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reducing_agent)" article in Wikipedia it says

> Good reducing agents are reagents that deliver $\ce{H2}$.

Wouldn't that make water unsafe to dissolve oxidizing agents?

Comment: I don't quite see how the statement about reducing agents is related to the safety of dissolving oxidising agents in water. Perhaps you could clarify this.

Comment: @bon I think OP means that water may deliver $\ce{H2}$ and is as such unsafe to dissolve oxidizers in.

Comment: Water doesn't deliver $\ce{H_2}$ though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the oxidizing agent is sufficiently strong, e.g. fluorine, yes. "[[W]ater spontaneously combust[s] under a fluorine jet.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorine)"

However, there are only a few oxidizers, such as fluorine, [chlorine trifluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_trifluoride), and [dioxygen difluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioxygen_difluoride) that can displace oxygen from water. More likely you'd encounter a strong reducing agent, such as Group I metals, that would attach to the oxygen in water, liberating hydrogen.

Comment: A 3% solution of hydrogen peroxide bleaches hair pretty well, and it is a neutral solution. In the lab, you can get a 35% $\ce {H_2O_2}$ solution.

Answer (score 0):

The safety arises from the solution's characteristics. Some oxidizers produce highly alkali solutions which pose personnel risks from chemical burns. This nature occurs to a lesser extent when dry chemical contacts the skin or mucus membranes ext. as the agent acquires water from the body and in essence forms saturated solutions at the contact sites.

Comment: It doesn't really answer this.